# How can I iterate over directories in the Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

The Windows command prompt (cmd.exe) provides the FOR command. It can be used to do an operation for any *file* in a directory. Example:

```
\> dir
28.05.2012  18:25                69 buildall.bat
28.05.2012  07:48    <DIR>          include
28.05.2012  18:23    <DIR>          sub-607

\> for %d in (*.bat) echo %d
```

How can I do the same thing (non-recursively) with all subdirectories in a given directory? The idea is:

```
for %d in (sub-*) do (
  cd %d
  dosomething
  cd ..
)
```

The for statement above does not find sub-607 becauses it's not a *file*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `for` command can take the `/D` switch to iterate over subdirectories, rather than files.

```
for /D %d in (sub-*) do ...
```

See here for more information: http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

Comment: Also: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909