# Add text to end of filename (but before extension) using batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch, rename, batch-rename

I have a list of files which are in the format on the left. I want to append a string to each file name, but *before* the extension, as shown:

```
File 1.txt  ->  File 1 version 1.txt
File 2.txt  ->  File 2 version 1.txt
File 3.txt  ->  File 3 version 1.txt
File 4.txt  ->  File 4 version 1.txt
...
```

In each case, the appended string is the same across all files.

This seems like such a simple task, but I'm having some trouble putting this into a batch file.

I've tried the `ren` command and followed some the the examples on [this page](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html), but the resulting file names append the string *after* the extension:

```
File 1.txt version 1.txt
```

Comment: The info at your SS64 "this page" link comes from this SU Q&A (with my blessing): [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](http://superuser.com/a/475875/109090) I maintain the SU answer (infrequently) as I discover new features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for longer filenames you will have to add some more `?` in the block with the mass of `?????????`

```
ren *.?* ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????" version 1".*
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so promptly!

I edited the command slightly, to retain the file extension, and to only affect txt files: ren *.txt ?????????????????????????" Version 1.txt"

Comment: what if I want to append something at the beginning

Comment: how many ? characters are needed?

Answer (score 52):

Instead of relying on *ren*'s undocumented quirks, why not do this the proper way?

```
for %a in (*.txt) do ren "%~a" "%~na version 1%~xa"
```

If you want to use this in a batch file just remember to double each % sign.

This line of code will loop through all the files matching `*.txt` and perform a rename command (`ren`) on each filename.  `%a` is the full file name, `%~a` is the filename without extra quotes added (quotes are added in the command). `%~na` is the filename without the file extension, and `%~xa` is the file extension.

If there is a single file, `File 1.txt` in the current directory the following command will be executed:
`ren "File 1.txt" "File 1 version 1.txt"`

Comment: Excellent! this is a better answer any day. +1

Comment: Do you have more documentation about "%~a" and others so we can make our own version?

Comment: See this question for more information about "%~": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/

Comment: This worked like a charm for batch-renaming files! Apologies if this is a super basic question (I'm very new to CMD), but how should this be modified to batch-rename folders instead of files?

Comment: Never mind, just found out about the /D switch from this other thread: https://superuser.com/questions/429752/how-can-i-iterate-over-directories-in-the-windows-command-prompt

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add "_A" to multiple files and this is how I did it.

I removed the extension first, added the suffix, then changed extension back to original. It sure did work for me and kept the batch code simple, as I am not much of a programmer.

```
@ECHO OFF

REN *.pdf *.
REN *. *_A.
REN *. *.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

Some help for Karan's answer:

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes ("")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
%~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable and expands %I to the
               fully qualified name of the first one found.
               If the environment variable name is not
               defined or the file is not found by the
               search, then this modifier expands to the
               empty string
```

Sorry, I can't answer to posts yet...

Answer (score 1):

For the folks who are inexperienced with command (like me), there are a couple of softwares that make bulk rename very easy:

- Bulk rename utility (no open source)
- Rename-It! (open source)

Answer (score 1):

@bwDraco's solution was good but it could have been kept simpler. My set of files were all *.jpg and I wanted to rename them all *c.jpg. You only need 2 steps for this, not 3:

```
ren "{filepath}\*.jpg" *.
ren "{filepath}\*" *c.jpg
```