# Why does this batch file fail on a "REM" line?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, comments

I refer to question *[Add text to end of filename (but before extension) using batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/603958/add-text-to-end-of-filename-but-before-extension-using-batch-file)* as I have the same problem. Using Windows 7 32-bit Enterprise (I know, I know ...) with all updates I wrote a tiny batch file `pdfrename.bat` with only three lines:

1. a comment, starting with `REM`  and *no* "hidden" continuation sign more to the right of the line
2. the proposed command, copy-pasted from the source [as provided by @Karan](https://superuser.com/a/604285/489136), commented out with `REM`
3. the adopted command for batch (doubling the `%`):

   ```
   REM Rework 2020-12-16
   REM for %a in (*.txt) do ren "%~a" "%~na version 1%~xa"
   for %%F in (*.pdf) do ren "%%~F" "%%~nF OdB%%~xF"
   ```

Running the command (3.) from the command-prompt,

```
for %F in (*.pdf) do ren "%~F" "%~nF OdB%~xF"
```

works fine.

But executing the whole batch-file `pdfrename.bat` from Windows explorer fails. Running the batch file from the command prompt `pdfrename.bat` produces an error message syntax error:

```
Die folgende Verwendung des Pfadoperators zur Ersetzung eines Batchparameters
ist ungültig: %~na version 1%~xa"
[...]
```

You need not to understand German. The important point is that **the error message refers to the commented out second line** (2.), not to the third line!

I tried to retype `REM`, inserted a tabulator after REM, inserted a second `REM` after the first (`REM REM ....`), inserted a third line after the second one with the same content and deleted the second line afterwards - nothing changed: the batch file terminates at the commented out second line with a syntax error. As soon as the incriminated second line is eliminated from the batch, the batch works fine.

I searched for "REM is ignored", but no luck, so I post the matter here. I never heard about or experienced before that the command processor tries at least to analyze a commented out line - and in the case that there is something wrong with the code after the comment-sign that it terminates the batch script.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rem

Comment: a workaround: if you wanted to provide an exemple: change this to say something like: 
`REM to do the same in a command prompt, divide the number of variable calls, for ex: %%f ,   by two. ie, only have 1 percent sign instead of 2`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### The error-msg refers to the commented out second line

This is due to the very complex parsing that is used by `cmd` to process scripts.

In short the parser processes `%` before pretty much everything else (phase 1) and throws an error as some of the `%`s need to be doubled as `%%` when used in a batch file.

So in a batch file:

```
for %%F in (*.pdf) do ren "%%~F" "%%~nF OdB%%~xF"
```

is a valid command and:

```
REM for %a in (*.txt) do ren "%~a" "%~na version 1%~xa"
```

is a broken command (the `%a` should be `%%a`, etc).

Note that:

```
REM for %a in (*.txt) do ren "%~a" "%~na version 1%~xa"
```

is a valid command **when run from the command line** as then the `%` does not need to be doubled.

`REM` would be processed in phase 2 of the parser, but it never gets there as the `%` processing in phase 1 has already generated an error and terminated the parsing.

For all the gory details of the `cmd` parser please read [parsing - How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)

Comment: Technically the `for %a in (*.txt) do ren "%~a" "%~na version 1%~xa"` *is* correct so long as it's not in a batch file itself. :)

Comment: @DavidPostill with other words "works as designed" - but not as described in tutorials. Even herer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rem

Comment: Another way to look at it: don’t think of REM as a comment, but as an internal command that does nothing with its arguments.

Comment: @EuroMicelli it's quite similar to the `true` or `:` command in Unixes, but working only inside batch scripts.

Comment: There are also _labels_ in batch scripts, which are written as `::` and are also often used as comments: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632524/what-does-double-colon-mean-in-dos-batch-files>

Comment: Batch labels actually start with only a single `:`. A label written as `::label` actually defines a label called `:label`. It is safe to use this as a pseudo-comment, however, because `GOTO :` has special handling for things like `GOTO :EOF`, so it's impossible to accidentally jump to a label that starts with a colon.

Comment: Wow, this just blew my mind. The CMD parser *processes text before acknowledging it's just a comment*. Just... *WOW*.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't work because even though it is "remarked" it is evaluated for substitutions, and *then* apparently discarded.

For "batch" your second line is incorrect and should read

```
REM Rework 2020-12-16
REM for %%a in (*.txt) do ren "%%~a" "%%~na version 1%%~xa"
for %%F in (*.pdf) do ren "%%~F" "%%~nF OdB%%~xF"
```

The corrections being that in batch programming expansions need to have %% rather than a single %.

Answer (score 10):

To add to the existing answers, although `REM` is used for comments, it is important to understand that it is actually a command that does nothing, not a comment. This is different from a Unix shell, where you have real comments and can add arbitrary text after a `#` character.

Not only the substitutes are evaluated for the `REM` command, also file redirects. So beware that the following line will delete the content of the file, because the `REM` command produces no output, but the empty output will be redirected to the file

```
REM some_command > important_file
```

**Edit**

As a comment pointed out, this is no longer true for modern Windows versions. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/10765659 there is now special handling of `REM` so that redirections are not executed, but this special handling occurs too late to make `REM` a true comment, as the substitutes are still evaluated.

Comment: Have you tested the alleged redirection issue? How exactly? In what OS? My tests (in Win 7 so far) don't confirm the issue, the content of `important_file` survives. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/10765659) states `REM` is special in phase 2 and "treated dramatically different". It seems what I observed confirms the other answer, not yours.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I didn't test this recently. A colleague had this problem in the time of early Windows, probably around or before Windows 95, and I avoided that ever since. I'm glad to hear that it has been fixed.

Comment: I was going to upvote this post for actually *answering* the question better than any of the other answers. But then I saw that, after seeing a comment pointing out an error in your post, you acknowledged it in another comment ***but you didn't edit the answer**.*

Answer (score 0):

This fact that REM is not a true comment but does some processing before being discarded points toward the answer to a problem in a batch file I had, one that I finally traced to a REM statement.

This statement in a batch file was meant only as a reminder of what this section was supposed to do:

REM '/?' flag

but instead consistently threw the error:

flag was unexpected at this point

Oddly enough, at previous points these lines produced no errors at all:

REM '-h' flag

REM '--help' flag

Because they worked, it was some time before I found the real cause. It was only by re-creating the original file line by line until I got a failure that I found real culprit.

Neither Google nor Bing could produce any results at all when searching for:

"flag was unexpected at this point"

although both produced plenty for:

"was unexpected at this point"

Perhaps REM was complaining about text following a flag it knew something of. I don't know.

In any case, when I changed REM to ECHO everything worked as expected. So I experimented a little more:

REM Testing '/?' flag

caused the error message to disappear as well.

I can see I'm going to have to be cautious about REM in the future.